# Mysqldump generated file that is smaller size then database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My database is 250 MB and dump size is 82 MB.
I am using latest MariaDB.
running this command:

```
mysqldump -u user -p database > t.sql
```

Comment: Well, that's not uncommon. And your question is what exactly?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189229/large-discrepancy-between-information-schema-database-size-vs-mysqldump-database

Comment: I wanted to make a backup. This is how I usually do it. But the difference in size is making me concerned. Shouldn't the dump file be larger because of the extra characters in it.

Comment: That depends on a lot of factors. The answer in the linked question on [dba.se] explains this pretty well.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider that makes sense, as we have just fresh installed new system and lot of tables are empty. Will test to make sure.

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly good excuse to restore from bare metal to confirm your backups perform as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The dump does not include the `INDEXes` other than the `PRIMARY KEY`.
- The dump does not include "free space" in the disk files.
- The dump is text, not binary.  For example a `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes in the file, but if, say, the value is "1" it takes 2 bytes in the dump:  "...,1,..." (the number plus one of the commas).
- On the other hand, some numbers, strings, dates, etc, will take *more* space in the dump.
- An empty table takes a minimum of something like 24KB on disk, but only a few hundred bytes (mostly for the `CREATE TABLE`) in the dump.
- The dump is a text file; look at some of it (via more or less or something like that).

So, your 3:1 shrinkage is quite feasible.  And a 2:1 expansion is possible.